# Problem with ParametricNDSolve and FindMaximum

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

I have a system 4 coupled differential equations:

```
a = a1 + g (1 - Cos[(2 Pi z)/h]); k = 96.29333; b1 = 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Pi/a)^2]; b2 = 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (3 Pi/a)^2]; Z1 = (w c)/b1; Z2 = (w c)/b2; s = 3.5 h; c = 
 1.257 10^-6; w = 2.8888 10^10;
With[{a = a1 + g (1 - Cos[(2 Pi z)/h]), k = 96.29333, 
  b1 = Sqrt[k^2 - (Pi/a)^2], b2 = Sqrt[k^2 - (3 Pi/a)^2], 
  Z1 = (w c)/b1, Z2 = (w c)/b2, s = 3.5 h, c = 1.257 10^-6, 
  w = 2.8888 10^10}, 
 sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[z] == -I b1 x[z] - 
      0.5 D[Log[Z1], z] y[z] + 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) u[z] + 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) v[z], 
    y'[z] == 
     I b1 y[z] - 0.5 D[Log[Z1], z] x[z] + 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) v[z] + 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) u[z], 
    u'[z] == -I b2 u[z] - 0.5 D[Log[Z2], z] v[z] - 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) x[z] + 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) y[z], 
    v'[z] == 
     I b2 v[z] - 0.5 D[Log[Z2], z] u[z] - 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) y[z] + 
      0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) x[z], x[0] == 1, 
    y[s] == 0, u[0] == 0, v[s] == 0}, {x, y, u, v}, {z, .1, 1}, {a1, 
    g, h}]]
```

When I run this,I got the solution as:

```
{x->ParametricFunction[<>],y->ParametricFunction[<>],u->ParametricFunction[<>],v->ParametricFunction[<>]}
```

I then run a code to maximize the function with conditions as:

```
F = x /. First@sol; G = u /. Extract[sol, {3}]; K = 
 y /. Extract[sol, {2}]; L = v /. Last@sol;
FindMaximum[{(G[a1, g, h][
      z] G[a1, g, h][z]\[Conjugate])/(F[a1, g, h][
       z] F[a1, g, h][z]\[Conjugate] + 
     G[a1, g, h][z] G[a1, g, h][z]\[Conjugate] + 
     K[a1, g, h][z] K[a1, g, h][z]\[Conjugate] + 
     L[a1, g, h][z] L[a1, g, h][z]\[Conjugate]), 0.098 <= a1 <= 0.104,
   0.016 <= g <= 0.024, 0.14 <= h <= 0.16, 0.1 <= z <= 0.6}, {a1, g, 
  h, z}]
```

But, I got some errors:

```
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable v. >>
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable v. >>
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable v. >>
General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolve::ndsv will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Please help me to resolve this....There is no problem if the parameter s is some number.But the problem comes when s=3.5*h.

Comment: Looking at it I would say it cannot work since you define say `a`as a constant by `With` depending upon `a1` as a parameter that is then solved for. A start would be making the definition for `a`and other values by using [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html?q=SetDelayed).